# perturbations in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Write

```
                 y''[x] + ( [Epsilon] * Exp[x/3] * y[x] )==0.
```

For [Epsilon]=0

Solve for y[x] with initial conditions

```
                            y[0]=y'[0]=1
```

Comment: Is `[Epsilon]` just a number? And you want the solution as a Taylor series in it? Note that the solution for finite `Epsilon` is Bessel functions.

Comment: If `[Epsilon] == 0` then `( [Epsilon]*Exp[x/3]*y[x] ) == 0` does it not?

Comment: You should not post your homework here for other to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eq = y''[x] + Epsilon*Exp[x/3]*y[x] == 0
soln = DSolve[eq, y[x], x]
```

gives an answer, and then you can even do

```
Series[y[x] /. soln[[1]], {Epsilon, 0, 2}]
```

which is ugly.

To add initial conditions, you just add equations:

```
soln2 = DSolve[{eq, y[0]==1, y'[0]==1}, y[x], x]//Simplify
Series[y[x] /. soln2[[1]], {Epsilon, 0, 2}]//Simplify
```

(where I've added `//Simplify` to force Mathematica to put it into nice form.